# Macports and scala

Tags: macports

I have installed scala 2.8 using macports. I have setup the SCALA_HOME env variable and I have added the bin directory to my path.

If I type scala-2.8 into my terminal I get the scala interpreter.

Problem is, I feel like my netbeans isn't able to run and compile scala because of the "2.8 part. If you download scala from the web and install manually you are able to just type scala and i suspect that's what Netbeans is expecting.

I realise that I can get around this simply by using the web version but I would rather use macports if I can

Is there any way round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the port [scala_select](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/scala_select/Portfile) When run this will symbolically link /opt/local/bin/scala to the chosen versioned scala executable. In your case you can point it to scala-2.8

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Just for idiots like me looking for this, you need to do this command: sudo scala_select -f scala28